# ValueError: continuous is not supported for RandomForestRegressor

Tags: python-3.x

After I had Pipeline preprocessed the weld data, I was able to get clean data in the output. Next, I need to pass the cleaned data through the model for training. Both the data preprocessing and model training steps can be further encapsulated in a Pipeline as follows:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
completed_pl = Pipeline(
    steps=[
            ("preprocessor", preprocessor), 
            ("classifier", RandomForestRegressor())
    ]
)

# training
completed_pl.fit(X_train, y_train)

# accuracy
y_train_pred = completed_pl.predict(X_train)
print(f"Accuracy on train: {accuracy_score(list(y_train), list(y_train_pred)):.2f}")

y_pred = completed_pl.predict(X_test)
print(f"Accuracy on test: {accuracy_score(list(y_test), list(y_pred)):.2f}")
```

I have used load_boston dataset from sklearn

And the error :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-d0b1928cf1a7> in <module>
     12 # accuracy
     13 y_train_pred = completed_pl.predict(X_train)
---> 14 print(f"Accuracy on train: {accuracy_score(list(y_train), list(y_train_pred)):.2f}")
     15 
     16 y_pred = completed_pl.predict(X_test)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    102     # No metrics support "multiclass-multioutput" format
    103     if y_type not in ["binary", "multiclass", "multilabel-indicator"]:
--> 104         raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))
    105 
    106     if y_type in ["binary", "multiclass"]:

ValueError: continuous is not supported
```

Comment: In target or pred values contains float data, should be int

Comment: Accuracy is not regression metrick

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values

Comment: thank you !!! i use r2_score for this ))